# Error scraping into a website (http.client.BadStatusLine: <!DOCTYPE HTML>)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to obtain the values in my website but I am getting this error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dayana/PycharmProjects/data-adquiring-system/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    result = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\Dayana\PycharmProjects\data-adquiring-system\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dayana\PycharmProjects\data-adquiring-system\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dayana\PycharmProjects\data-adquiring-system\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dayana\PycharmProjects\data-adquiring-system\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dayana\PycharmProjects\data-adquiring-system\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n'))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code I am working in is the following, I am trying to get the url content, then I need to obtain th temperature, humidity and rain data from the website, but I am getting that error:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://192.168.4.1'

result = requests.get(url)
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
```

And this is the HTML of my very simple webpage, those are parameters obtained from an Arduino with some sensors, also the page is in the Arduino.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>temp </p>
    <p id="temp">24</p>
    <p>hum</p>
    <p id="hum">19</p>
    <p>rain</p>
    <p id="lluv"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is the Arduino returning actual HTTP headers? BadStatusLine sounds like it's returning HTML directly.